# Discord v14 Dropdown Menu Template

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was trying to make a select menu by following the discord.js v14 guide, but I'm completely lost.

I tried to follow the steps given in the guide, but I'm confused as to where each part of the code goes.

It would be great if someone could help me with a template of a basic select menu, where there would be a default embed, and you could select from a few options in the dropdown menu, which would edit the embed that the bot replies with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Example of a selection menu from the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#building-and-sending-select-menus):

```js
const { ActionRowBuilder, SelectMenuBuilder } = require('discord.js');

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new SelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'Select me',
                            description: 'This is a description',
                            value: 'first_option',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'You can select me too',
                            description: 'This is also a description',
                            value: 'second_option',
                        },
                    ),
            );

        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', components: [row] });
    }
});
```

**Usage:**
[image]

---

I would highly recommend reading through the [initial guides](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin) in the docs before diving into more complex concepts. It gets tricky if you run before you can walk!